# LiveReload an extjs project using Sencha CMD

Tags: extjs, livereload, sencha-cmd

How would I go about using LiveReload to work with Sencha CMD. Is there a package that would allow me to do this? `sencha app watch` only watches files, but it obviously doesn't reload them in the browser, which is what I want. Any best practices out there for achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have also added [LiveReload Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei?hl=en) (or [Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/livereload/)) in your browser as well.

In LiveReload application add you project directory or just your app folder.

Conversely, if you're just making sass changes add your css folder to LiveReload application.

Once these are done, enable LiveReload extension and you're good to go